# Perl add column to an array

Tags: perl

The following array is the result of a database query, and I would like to add a column in Perl:

```
<snip>
foreach my $array_ref ( @stash ) {
    print "@$array_ref\n";
}
<snip>
```

Output result:

```
bash-3.2$ ./test.pl
2014 2 1
2015 2 1
2016 2 1
2017 1 0.5
bash-3.2$
```

I manage to add a row at the bottom.  For instance via the following code:

```
my @stashSum = ['Sum',  $sumNumDiv, $sumDiv];
push (@stash, @stashSum);
```

This results in the following:

```
bash-3.2$ ./test.pl
2014 2 1
2015 2 1
2016 2 1
2017 1 0.5
Sum  7 3.5
bash-3.2$
```

I am searching for the code to add the following as a column to the original array:

```
my $i=0;
foreach my $array_ref ( @stash ) {
    $totalDiv[$i] = $array_ref->[2] * 15;
    print "$totalDiv[$i] \n";   
}
```

The expected result is the following:

```
bash-3.2$ ./test.pl
2014 2 1 15
2015 2 1 15
2016 2 1 15
2017 1 0.5 7.5
bash-3.2$
```

Is there a way to 'push' a column onto an array in a similar manner as rows?  If not, how are columns added to an array in Perl?

Comment: `foreach my $array_ref ( @stash ) { push @$array_ref, "new_column" }`

Comment: Thanks works splendidly!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you seem to have is an array of references to anonymous arrays, to which you are referring using matrix terminology where columns refer to elements of those anonymous arrays, and rows are the anonymous arrays themselves.

Adding a column therefore involves manipulating each of those arrays in terms of prepending, inserting, or appending another entry in the right spot. [splice](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) is helpful for that kind of thing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;

my $x = [ [1], [2] ]; # Two rows, single column

my @tests = (
    [ sub { push_column($x, 3) },    [     [1,3], [2,3]     ] ],
    [ sub { unshift_column($x, 4) }, [   [4,1,3], [4,2,3]   ] ],
    [ sub { add_column($x, 5, 1) },  [ [4,5,1,3], [4,5,2,3] ] ],
);

for my $case ( @tests ) {
    $case->[0]->();
    is_deeply $x, $case->[1];
}

sub add_column {
    my ($matrix, $v, $col) = @_;
    for my $r ( @$matrix ) {
        splice @$r, $col, 0, $v;
    }
    return;
}

sub push_column {
    add_column(@_, scalar @{ $x->[0] });
    return;
}

sub unshift_column {
    add_column(@_, 0);
    return;
}


done_testing;
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I am still struggling with prepending a column to `@stash`.  For instance, I generate a numbering column:

Comment: `if (@stash) {
 for $i (1..$rowsDiv){
  my $n=$i-1;
  $Div[$n]=$i;
 }
}`

Comment: With the following as expected result:

Comment: `bash-3.2$ ./test.pl
1 2014 2 1 15
2 2015 2 1 15
3 2016 2 1 15
4 2017 1 0.5 7.5
bash-3.2$`